# how to update a name value pair (NVP) config file during install

Tags: wix

My custom Wix Dialog asks the user for an IP address and port number.  I then want to update a text file called config.txt as follows:

```
IP=192.168.001.234
PORT=45
```

Just like a boost property or qt config file.

I've used UtilExtensions:XmlFile to update a .NET config file but didn't see an easy quick way to modify a Name Value Pair config file.

Brute force would be to write a custom action that takes a command line tool that takes the config file followed by the NVP.

Comment: I answered this question on how I update text files, might be of use to you..:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876128/wix-get-value-from-paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Wix to write an [ini file](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_inifile.htm)

```
<IniFile Id="Ini1"
          Action="createLine"
          Directory="INSTALLOCATION"
          Section="Settings"
          Name="settings.ini"
          Key="IP"
          Value="127.0.0.1" />
```

Will output a file containing

```
[Settings]
IP=127.0.0.1
```