# Wix Toolkit only packages .exe

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I am trying to use Wix Toolkit for the installer of my application (visual studio 2013).  The issue being is that its only grabbing the .exe file of my application.  It is missing all the DLL, .config, pdb etc..

Now I know how to add these in manually but that seems kind of stupid.  What is the correct way of doing this?  This is what I have;

```
<Fragment>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyApp"/>
</Directory>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
 <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
<Component Guid="*" >
  <File Source="$(var.MyApp.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"  /> 
</Component>
</ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have already suggested using `heat` to achieve what you want, I would say the same, but I also wanted to link to another answer I gave on a similar subject which gives you an example, if you wanted to see some actual XML dealing with how to use `heat` in practice. You should be able to take the suggestions of the others and morph this into something that might work for you.

[Wix- How to copy a directory to install folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550763/wix-how-to-copy-a-directory-to-install-folder/26558025#26558025)

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WIX tool [Heat](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) to create a .wxs file based on a directory or even a,visual studio project.

Answer (score 2):

It's not stupid, it's simple and non-presumptuous.

If you don't want to create components by hand, you can use the heat tool.

You can use heat within a .wixproj by supplying parameters to the [HarvestProjects Target](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestprojects.html).