# Packaging PyInstaller app using Wix Toolset

Tags: python, wix, pyinstaller, python-packaging

I'm trying to figure out what would be the easiest way to create an Installer using [Wix Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/).

I'm building my app in Python and then creating an installer using PyInstaller as a One Folder (not one file) and then want to package it into .msi file. I saw [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550763/wix-how-to-copy-a-directory-to-install-folder) that I have to use heat.exe to create a list of all the files, but when I did that I got like 15,000 lines xml file that lists every single file. Not sure if that's the optimal solution or then could be some other way of properly packaging it.

Comment: Could you clarify, what is the problem with 15,000 lines xml file (if it is auto-generated)? You can probably optimize it a bit (using -sfrag -suid) to reduce the number of lines. Anyway, installing pyinstaller using MSI instead of PIP sounds like a strange idea - why do you need this?

Comment: Your question does not mention how Python or PyInstaller are involved in this. Why are they tagged?

Comment: Clarified why I tagged Python and PyInstaller. Because that's what I'm using to build binaries

Answer (score 1):

You can start by using `auto-py-to-exe` to convert your project into an exe file:

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

A .py to .exe converter using a simple graphical interface and PyInstaller in Python.

[image: Here is a demo :]

After this you can use any tool to generate the *.msi file such as Wix Toolset or Advanced Installer or other.

Comment: The question was regarding Wix Toolset and how Wix can be used to create .msi file using PyInstaller's Folder output.