# Install every file from source directory WiX

Tags: wix

Is it possible to install every file from a certain directory in WiX, rather than specifying every file in the folder?

Comment: Are you familiar with the **`heat.exe`** tool that you can use to generate WiX markup for whole release folders?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include all Files in Bin folder in Wix installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756311/include-all-files-in-bin-folder-in-wix-installer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `heat.exe` to install all of the files, [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899051/install-every-file-from-source-directory-wix#comment94655197_53899051) by [Stein Asmul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129130/stein-%C3%85smul).