# How to find the Windows Installer XML node in Visual Studio 2019 after toolset and extension installation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I am trying to create an installer with Wix and Visual Studio 2019. I am a Wix newbie so I just started to get something really simple working, from scratch. Therefore, I read [this explanation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html). I use Windows 10 build 19042.

Creating the winforms project does work fine for me but the next project does not. This is because of this step.

> Choose the **Windows Installer XML node** in the Project types tree,
> then select Setup Project

I can find Wix projects.

[image]

And I installed the Wix toolset.

[image]

So creating a very simple installer should be very simple. But in fact, it is not as I fail to do one tutorial step referring to a project type I cannot find.

You can help in these ways:

1. Tell me what to do the make sure the **Windows Installer XML node**
   becomes visible.
2. Provide the step to do the same without the **Windows Installer XML node**.

And logically, I double checked if the **Windows Installer XML node** is really not there. And it really is not.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***VS2017 vs VS2019***: I guess that explanation was written for Visual Studio 2017 - which is quite different for the "New Project" dialog. You can select "WiX" in the drop down button that says "All languages" in that dialog

***WiX Project Types***: Just double click the *"Setup Project for WiX v3"* - this is the project type that creates an MSI. The **"Bootstrapper Project for WiX v3"** is for making **`setup.exe bundles`**.

---

***WiX Downloads***: For the record, make sure you have installed both [WiX itself](https://wixtoolset.org/releases/) and the [WiX Visual Studio Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WixToolset.WixToolsetVisualStudio2019Extension). It looks like you already have (just mentioned for others who see this).

---

***WiX Training***: I have a few answers on WiX crash course and training material:

- [Short WiX sample links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305272/adventures-in-installing-a-c-wpf-application-wix/63308043#63308043)
- [Long WiX Tips and Tricks and samples links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)

---

A few selected examples from github (there are more WiX projects at the root level):

- https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXDefaultDialogsSample
- https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXLaunchConditionTest

Answer (score 0):

`Windows Installer XML` - Is listed as `WiX`. After installing the WiX extension, you just choose `WiX` and then you can choose the `Setup Project for WiX v3`